# How to use async, await in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make my code simple and I would like to use async and await for the code below. however, I don't know how to imply...It'd be nice to have some example codes.

```
deletePost = (post) => {
    var post_id = post;

    try {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/deleteAll/comments/${post_id}`)
            .then(() => {
                axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${post_id}`);
            }).then(() => {
                axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts')
               .then(({data}) => {
                    this.setState({
                        posts: data.result
                    })
                })
            })
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

.

```
// This is what i understand so far.
deletePost = async(post) => {
    var post_id = post;
    try {
        var deleteComments = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/deleteAll/comments/${post_id}`);
        var deletePost = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${post_id}`);
        var getPost = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts'); // How can I change the state here??          
        // return ??
    }
    catch {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty much there.

Only 2 suggestions

1. Since you are not using the response of delete calls you can get rid of them
2. Once you have the updated posts set state like this

   ```
   const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts');         
   this.setState({
        posts: response.result
   });
   ```

Full code

```
deletePost = async(post) => {
    var post_id = post;
    try {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/deleteAll/comments/${post_id}`);
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${post_id}`);
        let response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts');         
        this.setState({
             posts: response.result
        });
    }
    catch {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do (you don't need to save `undefined` values returned from the 2 first requests, and your code with promises isn't executed sequentially, the second promise isn't returned, so it isn't in a chain):

```
deletePost = async(post) => {
    let post_id = post;
    try {
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/deleteAll/comments/${post_id}`);
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${post_id}`);
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts');
        this.setState({
             posts: data.result
        }) 
    }
    catch {
       ...
    }
}
```

Of you can write even such way at the end of the code:

```
this.setState({
   posts: (await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts')).data.result
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see a lot of examples [here](https://getstream.io/blog/javascript-promises-and-why-async-await-wins-the-battle/), but to implement async/await in your function try using this code:

```
async deletePost(post) {
    try {
      const post_id = post;
      if (post_id) {
        // We do not assign the response to a variable because we do not need it for now.
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/deleteAll/comments/${post_id}`);
        await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/${post_id}`);
        // Assign the response to a variable to get the 'posts' data.
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/posts');
        const { result } = response;
        if (result) {
          this.setState({
            posts: result,
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('deletePost error:' , error);
    }
  }
```